# Where to ask why a crowdfunding project raised so much money

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask why did a specific crowdfunding project (I'm avoiding the name until I post the real question) raised so much money. I want to know why so many people thought it deserved to be given money for it to succeed.

Where should I ask about this? I thought about this communities:

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ (because it's a game)
- https://economics.stackexchange.com/ (because it's about economy)
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ (because maybe data specialists know why)

Answer (score 7):

I doubt if that question will fly anywhere within the Stack Exchange network because the answers will be opinion based.

Great chance there is no real rationale behind the investment decision. I doubt every investor will also be a member of the SE community and if they are they might not reveal their strategy.

I'm not sure if re-phrasing your question is possible but if there are specific conditions/terms in the funding proposal you could ask about those specific aspects. Based on looking through the help-centers of your proposed sites I rather advice you to study the help of [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ask your specific question on their meta to see if your re-phrased question would fly there.